# Use suffix while merging more than two columns

Tags: r

I tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74575047/20224217) way of merging columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

dfcheck <- data.frame(status = c("open/close", "close", "open"), stock = c("company energy","goods and books","other"), name = c("amazon1;google1","google3;yahoo1","yahoo2;amazon2;google2"))
dfdata <- data.frame(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"), title1 = c("amazon1","google1","yahoo1"), title2 = c("yahoo2",NA,"amazon2"))

dfcheck_tidy <- dfcheck %>%
  mutate(name = str_split(name, ";")) %>%
  unnest(name)

dfdata %>%
  left_join(dfcheck_tidy,
            by = c("title1" = "name")) %>%
  left_join(dfcheck_tidy,
            by = c("title2" = "name"),
            suffix = c("1", "2"))
```

For more than two columns:

```
df_in2 <- df_in %>%
  left_join(df_in_tidy,
            by = c("in_1" = "stock_name")) %>%
  left_join(dfedu_categories_tidy,
            by = c("in_2" = "stock_name")) %>%
  left_join(dfedu_categories_tidy,
            by = c("in_3" = "stock_name")) %>%
  left_join(dfedu_categories_tidy,
            by = c("in_4" = "stock_name")) %>%
  left_join(dfedu_categories_tidy,
            by = c("in_5" = "stock_name")) %>%
  left_join(dfedu_categories_tidy,
            by = c("in_6" = "stock_name")) %>%
  left_join(dfedu_categories_tidy,
            by = c("in_7" = "stock_name")) %>%
  left_join(dfedu_categories_tidy,
            by = c("in_8" = "stock_name")) %>%
  left_join(dfedu_categories_tidy,
            by = c("in_9" = "stock_name"),
            suffix = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

How is it possible to have more columns in order not to receive this error:

> ```
> Error in `left_join()`:
> ! `suffix` must be a character vector of length 2.
> ℹ `suffix` is a character vector of length 8.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> ```

Is it possible to have more than two columns for the join?
[1]:

Comment: Please post the data on `dfedu_categories_tidy`, perhaps with `dput(dfedu_categories_tidy)`.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that left joining 9 times is not the most efficient way to achieve your goal. Could you post what your desired output is?

Answer (score 2):

We can modify the original solution so that only one join is necessary, no matter how many stock names are needed.

```
dfcheck <- data.frame(status = c("open/close", "close", "open"), stock = c("company energy","goods and books","other"), name = c("amazon1;google1","google3;yahoo1","yahoo2;amazon2;google2"))
dfdata <- data.frame(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"), title1 = c("amazon1","google1","yahoo1"), title2 = c("yahoo2",NA,"amazon2"))
```

As in the original solution, reformat `dfcheck` so that it has one "name" per row:

```
dfcheck_tidy <- dfcheck %>% 
  separate_rows(name)

  status     stock           name   
  <chr>      <chr>           <chr>  
1 open/close company energy  amazon1
2 open/close company energy  google1
3 close      goods and books google3
4 close      goods and books yahoo1 
5 open       other           yahoo2 
6 open       other           amazon2
7 open       other           google2
```

Reformat `dfdata` so that "title1" and "title2" are replaced with "title_num" and "title_name" columns. In this way, there can be any number of titles, and we'll still only have these columns.

```
dfdata_long <- dfdata %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = 'title_num', values_to = 'title_name') %>% 
  mutate(title_num = parse_number(title_num))

  id    title_num title_name
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     
1 id1           1 amazon1   
2 id1           2 yahoo2    
3 id2           1 google1   
4 id2           2 NA        
5 id3           1 yahoo1    
6 id3           2 amazon2
```

Finally, join the reformatted data sets together and then use `pivot_wider()` to create your numbered columns. Note that this operation requires only a single join.

```
data_out <- dfdata_long %>% 
  inner_join(dfcheck_tidy, by = c(title_name = 'name')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = title_num, values_from = c(title_name, status, stock)) 

  id    title_name_1 title_name_2 status_1   status_2 stock_1         stock_2
  <chr> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>      <chr>    <chr>           <chr>  
1 id1   amazon1      yahoo2       open/close open     company energy  other  
2 id2   google1      NA           open/close NA       company energy  NA     
3 id3   yahoo1       amazon2      close      open     goods and books other
```